# Xamarin.Forms Frame content flowing out of bounds in Android

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app (4.6.0.800) & I'm making a control using Frame for the rounded corners. But the background color of grid flows out of the bounds of the frame on Android. It works as expected on iOS.

[image]

Here's the XAML code

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" CornerRadius="8" Padding="1" BorderColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               IsClippedToBounds="True">

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="FirstButton" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FirstButton_Tapped" />
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <controls:ShapeView x:Name="FirstBox" 
                                        CornerRadius="8" Margin="0,0,-4,0"
                                        ShapeType="Box"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label x:Name="FirstBoxLabel"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="SecondButton" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SecondButton_Tapped" />
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <controls:ShapeView x:Name="SecondBox"
                                        CornerRadius="8" Margin="-4,0,0,0"
                                        ShapeType="Box"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label x:Name="SecondBoxLabel" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```

I have tried adding `IsClippedToBounds="True"` but that didn't help either. I wonder what am I missing?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem . You could firstly remove  the child elements of Frame to check if the issue still exists `<Frame  HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
 IsClippedToBounds="True" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" />` . And You could provide the code of `ShapeView` so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT Here is the gist with code for ShapeView https://gist.github.com/prkhandelwal/5705603cf139025929386f431ec8835c

Comment: Did you try my code ?

Comment: I did try it removing all the elements and keeping just a grid inside frame. The background of that grid still flows out. This issue only occurs on Android. Things work as expected on iOS

Comment: Could you share your sample ?

Comment: U mean create a sample app & share?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214411/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-pratik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an existing issue on some version of Xamarin.Forms when we set the **BorderColor** . 
As as workaround , you could add an extra Frame as the parent layout of the CusTomView . In this way you don't need to set **BorderColor** any more . Check the following code .

```
// padding here will become the bordercolor of the frame
<Frame BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="1" CornerRadius="8">
            <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" CornerRadius="8" Padding="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               IsClippedToBounds="True" >
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid x:Name="FirstButton" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FirstButton_Tapped" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <BoxView x:Name="FirstBox" 
                                        CornerRadius="8" Margin="0,0,-4,0"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label x:Name="FirstBoxLabel"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="SecondButton" Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SecondButton_Tapped" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <BoxView x:Name="SecondBox"
                                        CornerRadius="8" Margin="-4,0,0,0"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label x:Name="SecondBoxLabel" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </Frame>
```

[image]